# Add missing rows to data frame equally distribueted

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I sampled a pandas dataframe using a custom sampler function. 
This is basically made up by two columns:

- a timestamp
- a value

I'd like to create a new data frame with all the datetimes equally distributed (i.e. every 10 minutes) to fill missing values in the sampled one (sampled at the same frequency).

Shoudl I need to use the *reindex* method?

I'm trying to do something like:

```
dd = pd.date_range(
        start_date.astimezone(pytz.utc),
        end_date.astimezone(pytz.utc),
        freq="3min"

    )
dd = dd.map(lambda item: calendar.timegm(item.timetuple()))
df.index = df.reindex(dd, fill_value="NaN")
```

It just does not works. I get a "length mismatch error" since the two indexes have different size.

Is this the correct approach?

Thanks,

FB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this, I used `comvibe_first` to merge two dataframe.

```
start_date = datetime.datetime.today()
end_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 19)
​
dd = pd.date_range(
        start_date,
        end_date,
        freq="3min"
​
    )
dd = dd.map(lambda item: calendar.timegm(item.timetuple()))
columns = ['some', 'column', 'headers']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=dd)
myarray = np.random.random((len(dd),3))
for val, item in enumerate(myarray):
    df.ix[df.index.values[val]] = item
index_new = df.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=200)
df = df.drop(index_new.index)
df_ok = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=dd)
df_ok = df_ok.combine_first(df)
```